# ODE distribution function in phase space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have an ODE system governed by the matrix $A$

$$ \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = A \mathbf{x} $$

Let's say I choose a large number of random initial conditions and let them evolve for some time $t$. These initial conditions will have some sort of distribution in phase space -- which I'm assuming can be described by a probability distribution function $f(\mathbf{x},t)$ --  that will evolve with time. Is there an equation that governs the time evolution of $f$? How would such an equation change if we add an inhomogeneous term?

Comment: Before we add the random bells and whistles. Do you know how to solve that ODE? Let's make it inhomogeneous from the start.

Comment: @KurtG. I know that $\mathbf{x}(t) = e^{At}\mathbf{x}(0) + \left [\int_{0}^{t}e^{As} ds\right] \mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{b}$ is the inhomogeneous term.

Comment: Fantastic. Then, if $x(0)$ is, say, multivariate Gaussian $x(T)$ will be multivariate Gaussian as well. Just with a new mean and variance.

Comment: Of course there is a caveat with the formula, namely it is only true if $A$ commutes with itself at different times i.e. $A(t_1)A(t_2) = A(t_2)A(t_1)$ for all $t_1, t_2$. If $A$ is just a matrix of constants this is automatically satisfied.

Comment: Another way of computing this is defining the flow map $\phi_t: x(0)\mapsto x(t)$ as a map from the phase space to itself then applying the standard change of variables formula for the density function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answers my question. $\mathbf{x}(0)$ could be anything, not just a Gaussian, and I'm trying to understand how a distribution of $\mathbf{x}(0)$'s evolves in time. @KurtG.

Comment: $x(0)$ is just a point and the phase space is a space of such points. Define a map that transforms the phase space according to the ODE (the formula you wrote does this for a fixed $t$) then apply the change of variables formula for density functions to map a density on $x(0)$ to a density on $x(t)$. They are related by a smooth transformation after all

Comment: @whpowell96 makes sense. I'm guessing I would end up with some Liouville-type equation in that case. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

You are likely interested in the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) of the (degenerate) stochastic dynamical system in $d$-dimensions $dX_t=AX_tdt$ where $X_0\sim D$ for some distribution $D$ with Lebesgue density $h(x)$. The evolution of the probability density function $f$ of the system is then given by the Liouville-type equation
$$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=-\sum_{1\leq k \leq d}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(\mu_k(x)f(x,t)),\quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$$
where $\mu(x)=Ax$ and $\mu(x)=(\mu_1(x),\mu_2(x),...,\mu_d(x))$ and initial condition $f(x,0)=h(x)$. For example, if $d=1$ we have $\mu(x)=ax$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and we obtain
$$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=-ax\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)-af(x,t)$$
which has solution $f(x,t)=e^{-at}h(xe^{-at})$.

Answer (score 3):

For the autonomous linear equation you have given, the flow map $\phi_t:x_0\mapsto x_t$ is given by $x_t = e^{At}x_0$. I have moved the time dependency to the subscript to emphasize that I am now interpreting the action of this dynamical system as a one-parameter family of smooth maps from the phase space to itself.

For simplicity, assume this system evolves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the random variables $X$ with density $f$ and $Y$ defined by $Y = \phi_t(X)$ or, equivalently, $X = \phi_t^{-1}(Y)$, with density $g$. We then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(y\in A) = \int_Ag(y)~\mathrm{d}y = \int_{\phi_t^{-1}(A)}f(\phi_t^{-1}(y))\left|\det\frac{\phi_t^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}\right|~\mathrm{d}y = \int_{\phi_t^{-1}(A)}f(x)~\mathrm{d}x = P(X\in\phi_t^{-1}(A)),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $x:=\phi_t^{-1}(y)$. Note that for finite $t$, this map is always invertible and smooth. We can then use the explicit formula for $\phi$ to simplify.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi_t(x) = e^{At}x\implies& \phi_t^{-1}(y) = e^{-At}y \\
& \frac{\partial \phi_t^{-1}(y)}{\partial y} = e^{-At} \\
& \left|\det\frac{\phi_t^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}\right| = \left|\det e^{-At}
\right| = e^{-\mathrm{tr}(A)t}.
\end{aligned}
$$
We therefore have $$g(y) = f(e^{-At}y)e^{-\mathrm{tr}(A)t}$$ or, in terms of the original time-dependent variables, denoting $g = f_t$ and $f=f_0$, we have
$$f_t(x) = f_0(e^{-At}x)e^{-\mathrm{tr}(A)t}.$$

Comment: We managed to post at the same time! Nice approach, I'm reading through it.

Comment: Glad to see we get the same answer when $n=1$ :)